# Measuring on a blurred image with OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, blur

I'm using a 3D scanner in order to scan rectangular objects and measure them (width and length). But, due to the position respect the sensor or also to the vertexs of the rectangle, blur appears at some sides. This causes the measure to have not enought accuracy.

What kind of preprocessing (OpenCV with C++) do you suggest me in order to find the correct contour? Do you think there is a better solution that using preprocessing? Note that the intensity of a pixel is a translation of it height respect the zero plane.

Here you have an example: a rubber on three different places. As you can see, blur appears at one side depending on this placing. The real size of the rubber is (at the image) 179x182 px.

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Forget to say that the blur affects different sides depending on the rubber's position respect the horizontal axis (middle row).

Comment: Here you have another example (I can't publish more than 2 links with my reputation):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj77m.png

Comment: do you know if your object is symmetrical? if so. you can ignore that blurred edge and focus on accurately detect the center of the object and then obtain the location of that blurred edge by applying symmetry.

Comment: It's a good idea, but the problem is that on many cases more than one side are blurred. Moreover, in spite of the objects scanned pretends to be symmetrical, the symmetry is very poor. This could put some noise on the measure.

Comment: Since you are using a 3D scanner, I believe you can make use of the depth information to discard those pixels (the blur). Then you should be able to obtain a fairly sharp 2d image. Does this make sense? Otherwise, why don't you use a traditional/2D scanner? you won't have those problems since the light is even.

Comment: Depth? Do you mean the height? If so, the intensity of the pixels represents the height, so threshold is not a good option (the blurring effect comes from the light diffuse reflection on the vertex, it's a 'defect' of the sensor). This defect causes that height contains wrong values at this places. That's the main problem...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you can ever measure it accurately if the image is blurred. I don't think this is a C++ question, it's a mechanical one.

Comment: Hi Ant. Thanks for answering. Yes, it's a mechanical question, but the solution can not come from this way: the sensor has blind areas.The unique way of avoiding this is to use another sensor (but it's not possible, there is no space for placing another sensor). So the solution comes by the way of the software. Using some preprocessing (or by calculus), it's neccesary to correct the accuracy. Sorry, I said wrong on my question: what we really want is to improve accuracy as posible. We're aware that it's not possible to get fine accuracy with code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a model/concept about the reason for the blur. Without it, there is no computation that comes closer to the *truth*. With such a model you may be able to adjust your computations. If for example your idea is that the blur is caused by the fact that the object is not orthogonal to the sensor and there is data from another side of the object you might want to cut off the object at the maximum value (closest to the sensor). For this you could use a threshold close to the maximum value. Please note that this is just an example.

Comment: Thank you, Gerriet. I know that it's an example, but (for other readers) I have to say that threshold does not always works, because some real sides (for example, the output side, at the end of the scan) have lower values that false-blurred sides. I'm thinking on mathematical models for estimating the blur. Maybe it could be the best solution (reducing each false-blurred sides in around 12 px would be great).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to de-blurr your image before doing measurement, it's all depends on the way the blurring happened, somehow you will need to estimate the way blurring happened. The simplest model is called shift-invariant mode, take a look at this link
[MATLAB link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-deblurring.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) and this [link](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/08/13/image-deblurring-introduction/)

Comment: Great, Samer. Thank you. I'll take a look. Could this  method cause some damages to the sharpened sides? I mean, should I need to make a local descriptor?

Comment: If you were able to model the blurring properly, then you will be okay. You will get a nice deblurred image. I do not see how the local descriptors will be helpful for more accurate measurement.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant 'local deblurring', my head got away. What I pretend to say is: it is better to evaluate the blurring before the sharpening so you can apply different sharpening levels on each side? In order to not to damage the sharpened ones.